# Service call failed: 400BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

I don't understand what is going on. When I run/debug my web application on localhost (win7/IIS 7.5) everything works OK. When I make deploy to external Server (win srv 2008 R2 Std/ IIS 7.5) I got bellow message.

Did I miss something? In the past, deploy was made from external Company and was worked OK. Now I overtaken the code and application don't work anymore in live. 
Can someone explain me how can I figured out what is missing. I don't know what data sould I provide you. Please help. Thank you.
Error: Service Call failed: 400Bad Request

```
    <?XML Version="1.0" Encoding="utf-8"?>
    ...
    path\FunctionName() in C:\path...
```

This path is the path of my Project Folder on my localhost, but on production Server is defferent. Is somewhere Settings for this path?

Comment: Show the actual error. The paths are just paths to the files on the machine where the assemblies were compiled.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for your answer. In Chrome I didn't see the whole error message. I tryed in IE again and saw that Problem was in DB - column missing.